# Is There a method to simulate scrolling on a tableview?

Tags: iphone, tableview

Is There a method to simulate scrolling on a tableview?
I'm using custom cell!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Scroll UITableView

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, <whateverYCoordinateYouWant>) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Start select some answers, or you'll find getting help really scarce. Just check the arrow next to the answer for this one and all of your previous questions.